# Is CoreDispatcher the WinRT equivalent to WPF Dispatcher in win8 app store apps?

Tags: marshalling, observablecollection, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

In implementing a producer consumer pattern with an `ObservableCollection` in WPF I've used marshaling techniques [like in this example](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/handling-cross-threading-in-observablecollection/) to ensure that the collection's events get dispatched on the UI thread as items are being created on a worker thread.

In winrt I can see how marshaling using `Dispatcher` like this:

```
public void AddItem<T>(ObservableCollection<T> oc, T item)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        oc.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(t => oc.Add(t)), DispatcherPriority.DataBind, item);
    }
}
```

could switch to `CoreDispatcher` like this:

```
public async void AddItem<T>(ObservableCollection<T> oc, T item)
{
    if (Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
    {
        oc.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { oc.Add(item); });
    }
}
```

- Is that an appropriate use of `CoreDispatcher`?
- Is there a better way to do this for a basic concurrent producer/consumer pattern in winrt?
- Without the same static accessor method as `Dispatcher` do I need to pass `CoreDispatcher` down from the UI into the marshaling code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've done:

```
public Screen(IPreConfigurationService preConfigurationService, INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _preConfigurationService = preConfigurationService;
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            if (!IsInDesignMode)
                _currentDispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        }

        public string UserMessage
        {
            get { return _userMessage; }
            set
            {
                _userMessage = value;
                SafelyRaisePropertyChanged("UserMessage");
            }
        }
   protected void SafelyRaisePropertyChanged(string message)
        {
            if (!IsInDesignMode)
                _currentDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => RaisePropertyChanged(message));
        }
        protected void ExecuteOnDispatcher(Action action)
        {
            _currentDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, action.Invoke);
        }

        protected void SendUserMessage(string message)
        {
            UserMessage = message;
            _currentDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => AlertOnError(message));
        }
```